# Where will NASA's InSight land on Mars?

Tags: mars, lander, site-selection, insight

Next year NASA is launching its [InSight](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/insight/) lander to Mars to study the rock deep below the surface, so they can try to understand how the planet formed. Where on the Martian surface will InSight land, and how/why was that site chosen?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

All four candidate landing sites were identified in the [Elysium Planitia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_Planitia) and the most likely landing site (pending final evaluation) will be this one, for providing the smoothest terrain in the landing ellipse:

[image]

And this is the context map:

[image]

Sources and further reading:

- [NASA Evaluates Four Candidate Sites for 2016 Mars Mission](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2013-269)
- [Single Site on Mars Advanced for 2016 NASA Lander](http://insight.jpl.nasa.gov/newsdisplay.cfm?Subsite_News_ID=37592)

Comment: It sure is close to Curiosity. Hmmmm...

Comment: Looks like about 600 km, so not close at all on the scale of roving.

Comment: Yeah, I'll update a bit to add a few things. Landing ellipse alone is 139 x 27 km with 99.5% confidence, about 470 km North of MSL. Terrain is also completely different to MSL's Gale Crater. I'll add some criteria from http://mepag.nasa.gov/meeting/2014-05/17_Golombek%20MEPAG%20InSight.pdf but am still searching for the February 24 MEPAG presentation slides that would include a bit more data from HiRISE.

Comment: @MarkAdler - Mark Watney disagrees. :p

Comment: Ok, but Watney has a much, much bigger rover.  Two actually.